# Why cp/mv can't be interrupted until the end of the current file

Tags: linux, cp, mv

Let's say I want to copy 3 large files (4Gb each) with this command :

```
cp -v file1 file2 file3 dest_directory/
```

When `cp` is copying the second file, and I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the copy is not canceled until the second file is completely copied.

So why this behavior? Does it have something to do with *system calls* or something like that?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel version `4.4.0-57-generic`.

Comment: That is unusual (not exceptional) behavior and I suspect it may come from the filesystem used.  So what FS are we looking at here?

Comment: My filesystem where linux is installed is `ext4`. But I usually use other file systems (other partitions, usb drives) like `FAT32`, `NTFS`. When you said it's **unusual**, you mean that it doesn't happen to you ?? you can cancel `cp` whenever you want and it is immediately canceled ??

Comment: That is right.  It stops immediately.

Comment: Does it happen when you copy things on the local hard drive or only with an external drive?

Comment: The same thing in both. The thing that where I was wrong is that it doesn't wait until all the file is copied, but until let's say 70% (I just retested it from local to local, and from local to USB drive).

Comment: A number (size) would give valuable pointers.  Drives have used DMA for decades now.  This means that the operation (read/write) is done directly between the drive and RAM so if the operation is less than the buffer size, it won't stop in the middle.

Comment: The time it takes is bigger if the destination is slower .

Comment: Using rsync to copy large files rather than cp command.Normally using rsync command for backup.

Comment: @JuliePelletier So that's the reason ?? But in that case, why windows doesn't have the same behavior ?? and why doesn't use my IOWAIT when it is copying ??

Comment: @Sidahmed Look at the output of `strace cp -v file1 file2 file3 dest_directory/`.